# My search function does not resolve to the correct render_template, and thus does not render the correct data

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

So I have an input field that allows me to put in some text, and with that text search my database for any items like it.

I have a very simple form class

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class searchForm(FlaskForm):
    seachInput= StringField('Search',validators=[DataRequired()])
```

This is rendered on my overview.html page like this

```html
    <div class="container-right float-right">
        <form class="form-search" method="GET" action="/overview">
            <div class="row row-searchbar justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-4">
                    {{search.seachInput(class_='form-control mr-sm-2')}}
                </div>
                <div class="col-0">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Now I think I have an idea of where the problem might be, because overview.html has multiple routes. one for /overview itself, another one for the pagination and finally the search query, it seems to always render this one

`return render_template("overview.html",pagination=pagination,filter=filter,search=search)`

```py
@routes_blueprint.route('/overview',defaults={"page":1})
@routes_blueprint.route('/overview/<int:page>')
@routes_blueprint.route('/overview/<string:search>',methods=['GET'])
def overview(page):
    """ Overview page """
    filter =  checkBox()
    search = searchForm()
    page = page
    per_page = 3
    pagination = Comic.query.paginate(page,per_page,error_out=True)
    if search.validate_on_submit():
        searchQuery = search.seachInput.data
        format = "%{}%".format(searchQuery)
        results = Comic.query.filter(Comic.comicName.like(format)).all()
        return render_template('overview.html',results=results)
    return render_template("overview.html",pagination=pagination,form=filter,search=search)
```

On my overview.html I use an if to check if any data is inside of the results variable

```html
        <div class="row row-comics justify-content-start">
            {% if results %}
            {% for comics in results %}
            <div class="col-3 col-comics">
                <h2>{{comics.comicName}}</h2>
                <a href="{{url_for('routes.details',id=comics.comicId)}}" class="ClickableImage"><img
                        src="{{comics.comicImage}}"></a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
            {% for comics in pagination.items %}
            <div class="col-3 col-comics">
                <h2>{{comics.comicName}}</h2>
                <a href="{{url_for('routes.details',id=comics.comicId)}}" class="ClickableImage"><img
                        src="{{comics.comicImage}}"></a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
```

Whenever I input something in my search bar the url will change to `/overview?search=yoursearchquery`

but the data will not be displayed on the overview page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure a better overview, I have written a simpler example. It may help you further. If you don't understand something, leave your question in the comments.

```
class Comic(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255),
        nullable=False, unique=True, index=True)
```

```
class SearchForm(FlaskForm):
    qs = StringField('Search')
```

```
blueprint = Blueprint('comics', __name__)

@blueprint.route('/search')
def search():
    form = SearchForm(request.form)
    qs = request.args.get('qs')
    items = Comic.query.all() if not qs else \
        Comic.query.filter(Comic.title.like(f'%{qs}%')).all()
    return render_template('search.html', **locals())

@blueprint.route('/<int:id>')
def show(id):
    comic = Comic.query.get_or_404(id)
    return render_template('show.html', **locals())
```

```
<form method="GET">
    {{ form.qs() }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<ul>
{% for item in items %}
    <li><a href="{{ url_for('comics.show', id=item.id) }}"{{ item.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

`form.validate_on_submit()` requires a valid POST request.

Comment: I transformed your code to my project and it's working now, was a lot easier than I thought. thank you !

Comment: Glad to hear that. Have fun.